# creating simulated uiTabBarController?

Tags: uitabbarcontroller

anyone have a solution to simulate uiTabBarController, can open multiple webview interfaces and retain the current pages there... but without the tabbar.so it can be controlled with a splitview tableview menu.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question has been answered in another SO question:

[How to Create a Custom tabBarController to simulate uiTabBarController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136346/how-to-create-a-custom-tabbarcontroller-to-simulate-uitabbarcontroller)

HTH - wg